# How to set timestamp on one column when multiple columns are updated

Tags: google-sheets

I am triying to set timestamp in goole sheets. I have this code but it only sets the timestamp when one column is updated and i would like to set the timestamp when multiple columns are updated. Could you help me with this problem.

Here is the code.

```
function onEdit(event) 
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-04:00"; 
  var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp 12hour Format . 
  var updateColName = "SINTHIA"; var timeStampColName = "FECHA SOLICITADO";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.



  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn(); 
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex(); 
  var headers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); 
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+2; 
  if (dateCol > -2 && index > 2 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself! 
   var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 2);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); 
   cell.setValue(date); 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use Array for Column names:

```
  var updateColName = ["SINTHIA", "Lu", "La", "Li"];
```

And use loop to check them all:

```
for (var i = 0; i < updateColName.length; i++) {
    // good code goes here   
}
```

And don't forget to replace `updateColName` to `updateColName[i]`.

Thats it!

```js
function onEdit(event) 
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-04:00"; 
  var timestamp_format = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // Timestamp 12hour Format . 
  var updateColName = ["SINTHIA", "Lu", "La", "Li"]; 
  
  var timeStampColName = "FECHA SOLICITADO";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  for (var i = 0; i < updateColName.length; i++) {

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange(); 
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn(); 
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex(); 
  var headers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); 
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName[i]); updateCol = updateCol+2; 
  if (dateCol > -2 && index > 2 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself! 
   var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 2);
   var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format); 
   cell.setValue(date); 
  } 
  }
}
```

---

Look in [Example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FmykOql6uHADbW5HAHg7qnAsBuOM0bpmfpN0bqHg26g/edit?usp=sharing)